# Redux + TypeScript + typesafe-actions: error with createReducer/handleAction, Argument 1 is invalid

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, typesafe-actions

I followed the tutorial on [typesafe-actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions) to create the simplest possible TypeScript/Redux project, however I can't get it working. I keep getting the error,

`Error: Argument 1 is invalid, it should be an action-creator instance from "typesafe-actions" or action type of type: string | symbol`

when I try to visit the page (Typescript is happy though, code transpiles ok)

Here's my **reducer.ts** (Single reducer, should just overwrite the store with newData). This appears to be where the error is originating from, the second argument to `handleAction`

```js
import { setData } from "actions";
import { createReducer } from "typesafe-actions";

const dataReducer = createReducer({}).handleAction(
  setData,
  (state, action) => action.payload.newData
);

export default dataReducer;
```

Here's the **actions.js** file (I've tried using both `action` and `createAction`, no difference):

```js
import { action, createAction } from "typesafe-actions";
import { SET_DATA } from "constants";

export const setData = (newData: string) => action(SET_DATA, { newData });
```

**constants.ts** is a simple one-liner,
`export const SET_DATA = "SET_DATA";`

As per the tutorial, I'm trying to use the fancy ["type-free" syntax](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#using-createreducer-api-with-type-free-syntax) in my Reducer code, so I also have a `types.d.ts` file

```js
// types.d.ts
import { StateType, ActionType } from "typesafe-actions";

export type RootAction = ActionType<typeof import("./actions").default>;

declare module "typesafe-actions" {
  interface Types {
    RootAction: RootAction;
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this should work for a very simple example. What am I doing wrong ere?

Versions FYI:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"typescript": "~3.7.2"
"typesafe-actions": "^5.1.0"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this isn't strictly answering your question:

We specifically recommend using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), rather than `typesafe-actions`.  RTK is already written in TS and works great in TS apps.

As part of that, RTK will generate correctly typed action creators from the `createSlice` function based on the reducers you define.

You can set up a brand new project quickly using [our Redux+TS template for Create-React-App](https://github.com/reduxjs/cra-template-redux-typescript/), which comes with RTK already configured to set up your store and type your `RootState`.

Also, we recommend *not* trying to follow some of the patterns listed in the `typesafe-actions` docs, such as trying to define a union of all possible action types. There's really no serious benefit from that approach.

See [the new "Redux Essentials" Redux core docs tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) for instructions on how to use Redux Toolkit and the React-Redux hooks API the right way, as well as [the RTK "Usage with TypeScript" docs page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript).